# System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I just updated to the latest ASP.NET MVC and I am getting:

```
Method not found: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary 
System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request.  Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not 
found: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary 
System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'.

Source Error: 
Line 12:         public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
Line 13:         {
Line 14:             routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
Line 15: 
Line 16:             //routes.MapRoute(

 Source File:  C:\ProjectX\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs    Line:  14 

Stack Trace: 
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary 
System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.CreateRouteValueDictionaryUncached(Object values) +0
   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute(RouteCollection routes, String url, 
Object constraints) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute(RouteCollection routes, String url) +7
   COP.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in C:\ProjectX\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs:14
   COP.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\ProjectX\Global.asax.cs:27

[HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary 
System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, 
HttpApplication app) +9935033
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext 
context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, 
IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, 
HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary 
System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9913572
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, 
HttpContext context) +254
```

I have followed this guide: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

I even 2nd passed the DLL list in the document as a check list to make sure I didn't miss anything. However, I am apparently missing something.

Comment: I have the same problem after I updated my NuGet package MVC 5.0 to 5.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try revert you Web.config and packages.config to previous workable version and downgrade the NuGet packs...
This is likely because your MVC has been upgraded while some relative DLL are still the old and incompatible versions...

I met a similar problem and I solved it by modifying Web.config under project folder as below:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" 
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: I ended up doing this, but I also purged my package directory and redownloaded. The combination fixed the problem.