# Missing Method exception "System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I've created a new project in Visual Studio 2013.2 with WebAPI and MVC enabled.  Right out of the box, compiling the generated project and running gives me the exception.  Looking around here, I've come across the following two questions:

[Mvc 5.1 MissingMethodException System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376261/mvc-5-1-missingmethodexception-system-web-webpages-typehelper-objecttodictionary)

[System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292286/system-web-webpages-typehelper-objecttodictionaryuncached)

Both these answers involve assembly redirects; however, in my case the assembly redirects are present and I'm still getting an issue.  My problem is that the GAC is loading version 3.00.11001.0 which is listed under assembly version 3.0.0.0 and my application wants 3.20.20520.0 which is also listed as assembly version 3.0.0.0.  (Note that in diagnosing the project I installed the 5.2 pre-release nuget package, but I had the same problem with the original versions, I just don't have those readily available)

Since the GAC is preferred over the bin directory, it seems that my development machine will always pull the wrong file.

Is it safe to remove these files from the GAC?  It appears that these are required for Visual Studio to produce Razor intellisense

Comment: Which framework version do you build against? If 4.5, have you enabled AutoBindingRedirects?

Comment: You can remove it from GAC, I guess Razor intellisense will work fine if you point to it in a web.config. You can even install the new dll in your GAC if you want.

Comment: Removing it from the GAC worked.  Haven't tested the Razor intellisense yet, but I don't actually do a lot of Razor work, so if you promote your comment to an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: Thank you Steve, but no thanks. You suggested the solution.

Comment: Hey @SteveMitcham. I am also having the same problem. Can't remove the file from GAC due to some dependency issues, plus other answers doesn't seem to help much. Can you please tell me some alternate answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the Assemblies from the GAC did behave exactly as expected.  The Razor intellisense for the project stopped working; however, the application began functioning properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the reference of System.Web to get it working.